# What's the correct way? Embed the whole list in a try or for any item in the list calculate the embed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, embed, embedding

I'm making a POC of FAISS for a semantic search and in this tutorial: https://www.pinecone.io/learn/faiss-tutorial/ they embed the whole list in a simple try:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ZcR.png)

In my case I have a list of tokens per user like this:

```
df['user_hard_skills'][0]
```

output:

```
['digital', 'teams', 'communication', 'business', 'cloud', 'fast paced', 'customer service', 'growth']
```

and for each string in the list above I calculated the embbedding with Universal Sentence Encoder (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# USeM
import tensorflow_text
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")

df['embed_user_hard_skills'] = [[embed(user_hs) for user_hs in eval(row['user_hard_skills'])] for _, row in df.iterrows()]
print("type:", type(df['embed_user_hard_skills'][0]))
print("lenght:", len(df['embed_user_hard_skills'][0]))
print("shape:", tf.convert_to_tensor(df['embed_user_hard_skills'][0]).numpy().shape)
```

output:

```
type: <class 'list'>
lenght: 8
shape: (8, 1, 512)
```

So my method to get embbedings is different from the example of FAISS usage and I don't certainly know if I'm missing something important.

I try to run the following part of the tutorial:

```
import faiss
embeddings = np.array([tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor).numpy() for tensor in df['embed_vacancy_name']]).reshape(len(df), 512)
embeddings.shape
```

output:

```
(12614, 512)
```

```
d = embeddings.shape[1]
index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(d)
index.is_trained
```

output:

```
True
```

```
faiss_index.train(embeddings)
faiss_index.ntotal
```

output:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [10], line 1
----> 1 faiss_index.train(embeddings)
      2 faiss_index.ntotal

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py:127, in handle_Index.<locals>.replacement_train(self, x)
    125 def replacement_train(self, x):
    126     n, d = x.shape
--> 127     assert d == self.d
    128     self.train_c(n, swig_ptr(x))

AssertionError:
```